# Is there a method in Microsoft Word to search and replace strings "01" , "02" , "03" with strings "1" "2" "3", etc.?

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I am designer creating an event calendar. Each listing includes an event title, description, date and time. The data has been retrieved from a database and brought into Excel where the date and time expressions have been formatted and concatenated to appear like this: Mon Apr 03 7-8 pm.

The table is then brought into MSWord where it is converted to text. I am hoping to be able to do a global find/replace for all instances of date numbers 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09 and swap them out in one go with their corresponding single digit formats, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, for the resulting example of Mon Apr 3 7-8 pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any other number zeros in the document? If not the easiest thing would be to Find and Replace `0` with nothing.

If you do have other zeros on the page that needn't be deleted I think you should do a Find with Wildcards for `(0)([1-9])` and replace it with `\2`.

Like this:
[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks so much Yisroel Tech. I will share this with my colleagues.

Answer (score -1):

By using `Ctrl + h` to bring up the find and replace dialog box then fill in find with "01" and the replace with, with "1". Then press replace all. Do this for 02,03,04 etc.